# Define all matrices $R$ that satisfy $R^2=A$ when $A$ is defined.

Tags: matrices

Matrix $A$ is defined as:

$$ A=\begin{bmatrix} 5 & 4 \\ 4 & 5 \end{bmatrix} $$

Define all matrices $R$ that satisfy $R^2=A$, $\quad R \in \mathbb{R^n}$
$$ R^2=\begin{bmatrix}5 & 4 \\ 4 & 5 \end{bmatrix} $$
$$ \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}5 & 4 \\ 4 & 5 \end{bmatrix} $$

$$ R=\sqrt{\begin{bmatrix} 5 & 4 \\ 4 & 5\end{bmatrix}} $$

But how do you compute something like this ?

If someone could provide some insight on this that would be much appreciated.

thanks,

tuki

Comment: By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, you can write $R^2 = pR + qI_2$, where $p=\operatorname{tr}(R)$ and $q=-\det(R)$. Now you can plug this to write $R$ in terms of $A,p,q$. This also gives an equation for $p$ and $q$ by taking trace and determinant, which allows you to determine all solutions $R$.

Comment: Have a look at the article about [matrix functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general for finding square root of a matrix try diagonalising the matrix or use Jordon decomposition to make the matrix similar to a diagonal matrix or a block diagonal matrix.

Comment: By diagonalising matrix $A$ we get:
$$ A=V^{-1}\Lambda V $$
$$ \begin{bmatrix}5 & 4 \\ 4 & 5 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\ -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 9 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} $$
Now what would be $R^2=A$ ?

Comment: see that $f(A)=V^{-1}f(\Lambda) V$ for any function f and see that sqrt is a function.

Comment: Not sure if i understand this. $f(X)$ where $f$ takes in parameter $X$ where $X$ is $n\times n$ matrix ? so what would be $f(A)$ ? $f$ is function for square root of parameter $X$ ?

Comment: for a diagonal matrix we have square root of it as the matrix with square root of its entries

Comment: could you give example of this ? sorry this is hard to understand since i am not familiar with concept of matrix functions.

Comment: $$f(\Lambda)=\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt{1} & 0 \\ 0 & \sqrt{9} \end{bmatrix}$$ ?

Comment: yes......................

Comment: I think i got it now and my apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: no its okay....

Answer (score 3):

If $R^2=A$ then $RA=AR$. Now $A=5I+4J$ where $J=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$.
The condition $RA=AR$ is equivalent to $RJ=JR$. One can show this implies
$R=xI+yJ$. But $(xI+yJ)^2=(x^2+y^2)I+2xyJ$ so one needs to solve the
simultaneous equations $x^2+y^2=5$ and $2xy=4$. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions is

$R=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 1 \\
 1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

indeed set

$R=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 a & b \\
 c & d \\
\end{array}
\right)$

you have

$R^2=
\left(
\begin{array}{rr}
 a^2+b c & a b+d b \\
 a c+d c & d^2+b c \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Therefore you have to solve

$\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 a^2+b c=5 \\
 a b+d b=4 \\
 a c+d c=4 \\
 d^2+b c=5 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

from second and third we get $b=\dfrac{4}{a+d};\; c=\dfrac{4}{a+d}$

and from first and fourth $|a|=|d|$

so the first equation becomes

$a^2+\dfrac{4}{a^2}=5$

which gives $a = -2,a = -1,a = 1,a = 2$

and plugging into the equations we get the others

$(a = -1,b = -2,c = -2,d = -1)\\(a = -2,b = -1,c = -1,d = -2)\\(a = 2,b = 1,c = 1,d = 2)\\(a = 1,b = 2,c = 2,d = 1)$

Hope this can be useful

Answer (score 0):

Method that works for this special case:

You have

$$a^2+bc=5$$
$$ab+bd=4$$
$$ac+cd=4$$
$$bc+d^2=5$$

By the first and the forth equation you have
$$a^2=d^2$$

By the second and the third equation you have
$$(b-c)(a+d)=0$$

But $(a+d)=0$ is impossible since the second and the third equation require $a+d\ne 0$.

Hence, one can conclude that $a=d$ and $b=c$.

Hence the 4 equations reduce to
$$a^2+b^2=5$$
$$2ab=4$$

Solving them, one get 4 solutions:
$$a=1, b=2$$
$$a=-1, b=-2$$
$$a=2, b=1$$
$$a=-2, b=-1$$

So the 4 matrices are
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1& 2 \\ 2&1\end{array}\right)$$
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} -1& -2 \\ -2&-1\end{array}\right)$$
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} 2& 1 \\ 1&2\end{array}\right)$$
$$\left(\begin{array}{cc} -2& -1 \\ -1&-2\end{array}\right)$$